# Solving $t^2y'+2ty=y^3$ by Bernoulli substitution

Tags: calculus, integration, ordinary-differential-equations, derivatives

$$t^2y'+2ty=y^3$$

The Bernoulli's substitution here is $z = y^{1-3} = \frac{1}{y^2}$, so $z' = -2\frac{y'}{y^3}$ so we have:

$$t^2\frac{y'}{y^3}+2t\frac{1}{y^2}= 1$$

so

$$=-\frac{z}{2}t^2+2zt=1\implies$$

$$-zt^2+4zt=2\implies -z+4z\frac{1}{t} = 2\frac{1}{t^2} \implies z-4z\frac{1}{t} = -2\frac{1}{t^2}$$

Finding an integrating factor gave me $u = \frac{1}{t^4}$, therefore the equation is:

$$\frac{z}{t^4}-4z\frac{1}{t^5} = -2\frac{1}{t^6} \implies \left(z\frac{1}{t^4}\right)' = -2\frac{1}{t^6}\implies$$

$$\frac{z}{t^4} = -2\frac{t^7}{7}$$

but it's completely different from the answer in my book. Where am I wrong?

Comment: The very end: $\int-2\frac{1}{t^6}dt=\frac{2}{5t^5}+const$

Comment: I don't see $z'$ anywhere.